# AngularJS Bindind Three Select Menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sample JSON Data:

```
[{"series":"Naruto","chapter":"300","path":"mangas\/Naruto\/300\/01.jpg"},
{"series":"Naruto","chapter":"300","path":"mangas\/Naruto\/300\/02.jpg"},
{"series":"Naruto","chapter":"300","path":"mangas\/Naruto\/300\/03.jpg"},
{"series":"Naruto","chapter":"301","path":"mangas\/Naruto\/301\/01.jpg"},
{"series":"Naruto","chapter":"301","path":"mangas\/Naruto\/301\/02.jpg"},
{"series":"Naruto","chapter":"301","path":"mangas\/Naruto\/301\/03.jpg"},
{"series":"One Piece","chapter":"788","path":"mangas\/One%20Piece\/0788\/00.jpg"},
{"series":"One Piece","chapter":"788","path":"mangas\/One%20Piece\/0788\/01.jpg"},
{"series":"One Piece","chapter":"788","path":"mangas\/One%20Piece\/0788\/02.jpg"}
{"series":"One Piece","chapter":"789","path":"mangas\/One%20Piece\/0789\/00.jpg"},
{"series":"One Piece","chapter":"789","path":"mangas\/One%20Piece\/0789\/01.jpg"},
{"series":"One Piece","chapter":"789","path":"mangas\/One%20Piece\/0789\/02.jpg"}]
```

HTML

```
<select class="browser-default">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Manga</option>
  <option></option>
</select>
<select class="browser-default">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Chapter</option>
  <option></option>
</select>
<select class="browser-default">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Page</option>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

I want to bind these select menus. First select menu belongs to series. Second select menu belongs to chapters and third belongs to pages. When you change first select menu Naruto to One Piece it has load One Piece chapters and last One Piece chapter. How can i achieve this?

Like this:http://mangayurdu.com/oku/One_Piece/803

Comment: Sorry but first of all stack overflow isn't a how-to portal. Basically, create new Object from your JSON data where you transform it. You only have one "Naruto" key with an array of all the chapters and images and so on. Than you could create something with https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select this tutorial. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the pattern of your json data I think that you can´t obtain good results with what you want to do. First because there are some unnecessary data in that json, and second because you should take this json and parse it with extra code for order data. I think that you could see every element like and compound object, beginning with name of the serie, inside this the list of chapters and inside every chapter their pages or images. The idea when you play with data is obtain good time of response. Hope this help you.